# Regex Exclude Comments

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I want to have a Regex that will not return the strings that are enclosed in html comments starts in `<!--` and/or ends in  `-->`

I currently only have this to check if it is starting in `<!--` and has a text equal to `hello`:

```
^(?!<!--).*hello.*$
```

It seems to work fine but when I test my examples that are multiline, it doesn't return any match at all.

Here is what I test it with:

```
hello there
<!- hello there -->
<!-- hello there -->
```

So I expect that the first two would be returned as matches:

```
hello there
<!- hello there -->
```

But this Regex test returns no result, unless I only have the first line (`hello there`) given:
[regexr.com/5t1ng](http://regexr.com/5t1ng)

Help anyone?? And how to have a Regex check to exclude in matches if ending in `-->`?

That is, I expect that:

- `<!-- hello` - shouldn't match
- `hello -->` - shouldn't match
- `<-- hello -->` - shouldn't match
- `<!- hello`  - should match
- `<-- hello`  - should match
- `<-- hello ->` should match

Thanks!

Comment: Obligatory note about [the futility of parsing X/HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/62576). Use a DOM parser instead, and comments are irrelevant.

Comment: You have to enable the `m` for multiline flag at the right top, see https://regexr.com/5t26m

Comment: It is very brittle, but you might match the examples with `^(?!<--.*-->$|<!--|\w.*-->$).*\bhello\b.*` https://regex101.com/r/b5b7Ww/1

Comment: `<-- hello -->` **should** match according to what you said.

Comment: @keechan Did that work out?